# Get only city names with Google Maps API autocompletion

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I use this code to provide **autocompletion of location names** thanks to the Google Maps API:

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('adr'));
```

```html
City : <input id="adr" type="text" class="form-control" value="" >
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All locations names are provided, like city names "Paris", but also country names "Germany", region names, etc.

How is it possible to have autocompletion but for **city names** only? i.e. no street names, no country names, no region names ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's in the doc : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(yourHTMLElement, { types: ['(cities)']});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to restrict to a specific country, and to get the Zipcode from a city that was written. Example: Paris -> 75000

Comment: Yes, for this i use the componentRestrictions property. You can add a country restriction using the country ISO2 code. You can do it int the Init `var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(yourHTMLElement, { types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions : { country: 'fr' }})` or dynamically `autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ country: 'fr' })`. Refs : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('adr'),
  { 
    types: ['(cities)']
  }
);
```

```html
City : <input id="adr" type="text" class="form-control" value="" style="width:100%">
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43512324/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).